# Ubuntu Re-Installation problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I wanted to remove Ubuntu from my pc (which I had dual booted), and reinstall it.
To do this, I went to the disk management in Windows, formatted the space for Ubuntu, and reallocated the partition for Windows to use.

So when I again thought of dual booting with Ubuntu, using the advanced start up option in windows, my USB was not detected. I even checked the firmware settings. There is only one option in the advanced start up menu called Ubuntu, and if I choose this option a black screen appears with GNU and grub.

I want to fix this. Can anyone help?

Comment: The installer is seen in UEFI boot menu as the name/label of flash drive. But if flash drive not configured as bootable then it will not be shown. Also many with Secure boot do not allow booting other devices as not secure. Either turn off Secure boot or see if separate setting to allow USB boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean up boot sector so that Ubuntu entry is gone.
Follow the instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392)

At Windows command prompt

```
Bootrec.exe /FixMbr

Bootrec.exe /FixBoot
```

Note : Bootrec.exe is located under C:\Windows\system32

Once that is done, restart the computer and then install Ubuntu using the live USB.

Comment: I was about to answer my own question with the above solution.But Thank you anyways.
I just went to the advanced options in the troubleshoot method of the advanced startup.Entered the command prompt and executed the command and reinstalld ubuntu alongside windows.